# How to plot accuracy vs max_depth in python?

Tags: python

I want to find optimal value for max_depth for my decision tree.

So wrote following:

```
max_depth_range = list(range(1, 6))
accuracy = []
for depth in max_depth_range:

    clf= DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = depth, 
                             random_state = 0)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    accuracy.append(score)
```

now I want to plot max_depth vs accuracy to show optimal max_depth, like in the picture but I could not plot it, can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling "Python plot"? The first result for me is [the `matplotlib` library](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot max_depth vs accuracy as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

accuracy = [0.55, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95]
max_depth = list(range(1, 6))

plt.plot(max_depth, accuracy) #adds the line
plt.plot(3, 0.95, marker='o') #adds the point
plt.grid() #adds a grid to the plot
plt.ylabel('accuracy') #xlabel
plt.xlabel('max depth') #ylabel
```

Note that i took random numbers for the values in your accuracy array since the exact numbers were not provided.

The output will look as follows:

[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Jjd.png)